# Racket variable memory

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

***Given this code:***

```
(define (wrapper n)
  (define (sum-ints)
    (set! n (+ n 1))
      (display n)(newline)
      (if (= n 3)
        n
        (+ n (sum-ints))))
  (sum-ints))
```

***Calling this procedure with*** `n = 0`

```
(wrapper 0) => 
  1
  2
  3
  6
```

I had expected the process to increment n to a value of 3, and then as it returns, add 3 to 3 to 3 for an output of 3 3 3 9.

*Does the inner procedure store a shadow copy of n?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oog, mutation is nasty. The issue here is that "plus" is evaluated left-to-right. Specifically, let's consider the case when n=2. The expression `(+ n (sum-ints))` is evaluated left-to-right. First, the identifier `+` evaluates to the plus function. Then, `n` evaluates to 2. Then, the recursive call is made, and the result is 3. Then, we add them together and the result is 5.

You'll see the same result in Java, or any other language that defines left-to-right evaluation of subexpressions.

Solution to this particular problem, IMHO: don't use mutation. It's needed in only
about 10% of the cases that people want to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation.